# handling large CSV file with over 30 million entries in browser

Tags: r, csv

I have a large CSV file with over 30 million entries, i succeeded importing its data in R but when i render in an html table in a browser some records are not displayed. Could you share your way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fread` function of `data.table` package.